# push() inside chrome.tabs.query doesn't add to array properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

So I'm having a problem that I can't quite figure out myself even after hours of trial and error and of course multiple queries on this site.

I'm basically trying to fill an array with the titles of all tabs open in Chrome, but see for yourself:

```
var children = [];

function updateList(){
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
        for( i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            children.push(tabs[i].title);
        }
    })
    children.push("test")
}


console.log(children);
console.log(children.length);
updateList();
console.log(children);
console.log(children.length);
```

My problem is that the array entries that I'm push()-ing inside of the tabs query aren't really handled like they're array entries. They show up in the console when I'm inspecting the array and they do change the length according to Chrome, but when I log the length of the array they're not counted. Nor can I access them by doing something like:

```
children[2]
```

I have no idea what is causing this, but I hope that someone on here can tell me what is!

---

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I've for some reason not tried out to manually check the length of the array in the Chrome console, but I've done that now. The length is correct, so it seems that the query takes too long for it to take effect. Now the question is: how do I force my program to wait for the query to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) is async, which is why it takes a callback. To ensure the `query` callback is finished add own of your own to `updateList` like this:

```
var children = [];

function updateList(callback){
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
        for( i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            children.push(tabs[i].title);
        }

        children.push("test")
        if (callback) {
          console.log('calling updateList callback');
          callback();
        }
    })
}


console.log(children);
console.log(children.length);
console.log('calling updateList')
updateList(function() {
  console.log('in updateList callback');
  console.log(children);
  console.log(children.length);
});
console.log('called updateList');
```